# Why return xml instead of value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How can I add style information to the xml returned from my web service?

Example:

```
public class ServiceController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/service
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/service/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/service
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/service/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/service/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
```

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<ArrayOfstring><string>value1</string><string>value2</string></ArrayOfstring>
```

I am using the url:
http:/api/Service

Why it is returning xml file?

Answer (score 0):

This is because Web api works on http verbs when you type http:/api/Service this in your browser the first method you will called is Get where you are returning IEnumerable of string and that's why its returning it.

If you want to return single value then write something like this.

```
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Value";
    }
```

Another thing you have putted another implementation of get also which will return single string value. But for that you need to pass parameter in URL.

Like http:/api/Service/5 which will call your Get(int id) method.